# Ionic - Logout function that works in several pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to make a function `logout()` that basically cleans up my `LocalStorage` and then redirects to my `LoginPage`

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(authenticated_user_key_name); // "authenticated_user"

    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
}
```

But I want to call this function in several pages, `HomePage`, `HomeUserPage`, `ChatPage`

I know that I can place this function in my `app.modules.ts` but I want to separete these function, `login()`, `logout()`, `refreshToken()`, etc...

I don't undestand very well ionic structure yet, so what should I create?

- Another page
- Pipe
- Component
- Directive
- Provider

I alredy tried with an provider, `AuthProvider`, but I discovered that I can't import `navController` inside an provider, so, I cant redirect to my `login` page when I `logout`

Where should I put these global functions?

Comment: one more note - I see that you are not using lazy loading. So in my examples below I use "string" as name of pages since I use lazy loading. You will need to make sure all your pages are imported correctly and instead of strings you can then use Component references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things structured and clean I would recommend you assess your needs for methods/features that should be "provided" across many pages/components and create a new **foundation.provider.ts** that can do:

- auth (like your case)
- analytics (like MixPanel or Google Analytics etc)
- etc

So you need to:

1. add a new provider to your project (create foundation.provider.ts in your providers folder)
2. import it into your app.module.ts (do import and and to providers sections in Ngmodule)
3. then import it as needed into your pages/components

Update:
since the question also includes ability to push a page to navstack - that is not normally available to provider (NavController requires a component).

To solve this there are a couple of strategies:

1. Leverage side menu and place button (Logout) in there to make it available across the entire app regardless of page. This way you direct user to side bar to logout of  the app and the side menu is available across all the app pages:

[image]

This will require a button in your app.component

```html
<button ion-button block clear menuClose (click)="logout()">LOGOUT</button>
```

and the code in the app.component.ts:

```
logout() {
    // cleans out data and sets login page as root:
    this.foundation.logout();
    // does navigate user
    this.nav.setRoot('LoginPage');
}
```

2. If you still require placing a logout button on multiple pages within the app (not great UX btw). Then you can do split logic approach: inside a page when logout button is pressed you call:

```html
    <button ion-button outline (click)="this.foundation.logout(); this.nav.setRoot('loginPage')">
          Logout
    </button>
```

Hope this is clear.

There is a 3rd option which is hacky - to import App into your foundation and call getActiveNavs() method. But I would not recommend this.

Comment: Thank you, I think I undestand what I have to do, I'll try and if I get stuck I come back

Comment: Ok, so I got stuck, I have the privder and the foundation imported and working, but How do I call my `navCtrl` inside the provider or the foundation?

Comment: when I import navController to my provider, `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {` it returns an error `No provider for NavController!`

Comment: and if I add `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {` to my `foundation.provider` it returns another error `Can't resolve all parameters for FoundationProvider: (?)`

Comment: That probably will be helpful, thank you for your time :D

Comment: yes I see your point, nav controller requires a component (for Nav to be accessible), I will edit my answer in 30 min to render how you can do it

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you, one more thing, you said me to create the foundation in my providers folder, can I create a foundation just to my auth provider? Ex.:  `providers/auth/foundation.auth.ts`or than `providers/auth/foundation.provider.ts`

Comment: ah;) this is more of a convention really. But I would highly suggest you to follow this style guide in naming and file locations: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide I presonally thought before "who cares" but it made a very big difference in terms of code maintenance. So if foundation is meant to be everywhere I would say it should be its own provider